# change Image Button System Resource when clicked

Tags: java, android, button, click

I want to change e.g. the btn_star_big_off to btn_star_big_on

Everytime someone clicks on the button the state of that should change. Toogle would be perfect, but I don't know how to combine that. And I don't know how to change state of the button. I found out that I could do that with the drawable XML File but there I only have access to the images I imported, but not the the system resource ones?

The Button:

```
<ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off" />
```

And here is the trial from my drawable XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button" android:state_pressed="true"/>
 <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button"/>
 <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

Comment: Try to change the image programatically onclick event of your view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use ToggleButton

1) In your layout, implement ToggleButton

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ToggleButton
    android:layout_width=0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".3"
    android:background="@drawable/my_button"
    android:text=""
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""/>

</TableRow>
```

2) Creation xml layout in drawable directory ( here my_button.xml )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" android:state_pressed="true"/><!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" android:state_focused="true"/><!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

here i add an another state, if you want to have an focused img

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot, but there is still a problem. When I do it like that, I get an error:

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/btn_star_big_off').

Because I haven't saved the images on my pc, they are from android (from the System Resource). How can I respond System Resource Images?

Comment: no problem ! my code has been edited. if its ok for you click up :)

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but now i have two problems again:

The first is that ON and OFF is shown as a text in front of my symbol.
The second one is that the image is scaled, but I want it in the origin size. 

Do you have any suggestions for me :-)

Here is what it looks like
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20731482/star.jpg

Comment: no problem my friend !
I update my toggle button with text, textOn and textOff
For toggleButton.
Do you add layout_width="wrap_content" on togglebutton ( and no match_parent ) ?

Comment: I use wrap_content (the same you post me). Probably the problem is that I am using this inside a TableRow ?

Comment: now ToggleBUtton take 30% off total match_parent width
( .3 = 30% , .1 = 10% )

Comment: yeah ! so up for the best answer :)